# How do I run my selenium ruby scripts on different browsers?

Tags: ruby, selenium

I have written my script specifically for FF. Now I wish to run that same script on Chrome as well as IE. Also I want to run my tests in following order :

1. Open browser1.
2. Run script on that browser.
3. Close browser1.
4. Open browser2.
5. Run script on that browser.
6. Close browser2.

Please help.

Comment: Could you please show us the code you've written so far? Or at least a sample of it?

Comment: Why not in the same browser ? as you are opening the second browser, after closing the first browser.. Then why need 2 browsers.. Could you be specific ?

Comment: Why you don't use each script for each browser? The selenium concept (in my opinion) isn't run only one script in many browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to run your tests on :

1.Chrome : you will need to install latest Chrome driver, unzip it and paste its path in the environment variables.

2.IE : you will need to install IEDriver server unzip it and paste its path in the environment variables and enable protected mode for each zone in following way (Internet options->security tab->enable protected mode checkbox).

For running your tests as per the way you mentioned, not sure what framework you're using or whatever, but you can do this with a loop. You can do the following :

```
    def all_browsers
       browsers = [:firefox,:chrome,:ie].each do |br|
       $driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for br
       $driver.manage.window.maximize
       $driver.navigate.to("http://google.com")
       end
       $driver.quit
    end
```